# Invariant functions on the space of finite sequences of reals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $S$ be a space of all finite sequences of real numbers (we don't endow it with metric or topology in general). Before asking the main question, some notation.

**1.** For each $\mathbf s\in S$ we define $|\mathbf s|$ to be the length of $\mathbf s$.

**2.** Let $\mathbf s',\mathbf s''\in S$ be equivalent ($\mathbf s'\sim \mathbf s''$) if $|\mathbf s'| = |\mathbf s''|$ and $\mathbf s''$ can be obtained by $\mathbf s'$ by only permuting elements of $\mathbf s'$. Say, $\{1,2,3\}\sim\{2,3,1\}$.

**3.** Define an addition of sequences in the following way:
$$
\mathbf s = \mathbf s'+\mathbf s'' = \{s'_1,...,s'_{k},s''_1,...,s''_{l}\}.
$$
where $k=|\mathbf s'|$ and $l = |\mathbf s''|$ and multiplication by scalar:
$$
\alpha\mathbf s = \{\alpha s_1,...,\alpha s_{|s|}\}.
$$

**4.** For $n\in\mathbb N$ put $\mathbf 1_n = \{1,1,...,1\}$ such that $|\mathbf 1_n|=n$.

In probability theory often the following function $L\to \mathbb R$ are used: 
$$
\min \mathbf s = \min_{1\leq i\leq |s|}s_i,
$$
$$
\max \mathbf s = \max_{1\leq i\leq |s|}s_i,
$$
$$
\overline{\mathbf s} = \frac{1}{|\mathbf s|}\sum s_i.
$$

All these functions have a nice invariance property: $f(\mathbf s) = f\left(\mathbf s+f(\mathbf s)\mathbf 1_n\right)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. I am interested if this class of functions was already discussed in details?

---

Some thoughts:

**a)** if we put $S$ to be a class of real-valued continuous maps with compact domains from $\mathbb R$ then we can extend these three functions to admit the same property. Moreover, the outcome for each of these functions will be in an image of $\mathbf s$.

**b)** all these three functions are constant on class of equivalence $[\mathbf s]$ for any $\mathbf s\in S$.

**c)** For sure, $\overline{\mathbf s}$ is an expectation with respect to class of uniform probability measures each of them defined over a finite set. So, we can extend it to a wider class of measures. On the other hand, then we will lose the property **b)**.

**d)** Constant function of course also admit these property, however is not of too much interest.

Comment: @joriki: thanks for boldface. Also added d) and continuity in a).

Comment: You're welcome -- I added some more :-)

Comment: A few more examples: Assuming that $\mathbf{s}$ is listed in non-decreasing order and that $n=|\mathbf{s}|$, define $r_k(\mathbf{s})=s_k$ if $k\le|\mathbf{s}|$, $r_k(\mathbf{s})=s_n$ otherwise; then $r_k$ has the property, as do the corresponding ‘rank from the top’ functions and the median. If $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\min\{x,y\}\le f(\{x,y\})\le$  $\max \{x,y \}$, then $\mathbf{s}\mapsto f(\min\mathbf{s},\max\mathbf{s})$ has the property. All of these examples satisfy $f(\mathbf{s'})=\mathbf{s}$ whenever $\mathbf{s'}$ is the sum of finitely many copies of $\mathbf{s}$.

Comment: I do believe that the any of the power means (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_mean) would be invariant (special cases for $-\infty, \infty$ and $1$ already mentioned). I believe you can find many more invariant functions as other means (median has been mentioned, the most common number with some way of handling a tie, and so on)

Comment: I don't know about the invariant function aspect, but your equivalence classes are called "multisets" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset (basically a set which can contain multiple copies of the same element). Specifically, you are considering finite multi-subsets of the reals.

Comment: Note also that if this holds for n=1 it holds for all n.